# Prove that $HIGD$ is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

$EF$ is the mid segment of isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$. $AG$ is a height. The diagonals intersect $EF$ at points $H$ and $I$.

Prove $HIGD$ is a parallelogram.
[image: Picture]

I tried showing $HI=DG$ but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $BK$ is an altitude of the trapezoid.

Thus, $DG=CK$ and $$HI=EI-EH=\frac{1}{2}DC-\frac{1}{2}AB=DG.$$

Comment: Why does the last equality hold?

Comment: @Orangalo Because $GK=AB$ and $DG=CK=\frac{DC-AB}{2}$.

Comment: Did you mean $GK=AB$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Orangalo You are welcome!